# UI notification of task completion

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I build a Typescript project, I have no indication that the build task was completed (besides that when I try to repeat the build and it is still running, I get a warning:

> There is an active running task right now. Terminate it first before executing another task.

There doesn't seem to be any change in the UI, and nothing in the Output pane.

How can I know whether a task is currently running in Visual Studio Code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a spinner in the left hand side of the status bar, which is visible when tasks are still running:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have foud this extension to work well in this case:

[Task notifier](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=joelrobichaud.vscode-task-notifier)

It does not have much controls and trigger a system notification (I'd love we could trigger a vscode noification). But that do the job for me :)

I may contribute to it one of these days, or you may as this could be easily done with vscode api for extensions!

Answer (score 0):

A non-visual, but builtin notification option: Courtesy of [issue #141506](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/141506) and corresponding [PR #160828](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/160828), [since VS Code 1.73](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_73#_new-audio-cues), you can put the following in your [settings.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson):

```json
"audioCues.taskCompleted": "on",
"audioCues.taskFailed": "on",
```

As for visual builtin things, I don't know of a generalized way to get notified visually when a task is done, but while a task is running, the status bar has a "Running Tasks" section (can only be toggled on or off in the status bar context menu while a task is running) that will show a tools icon ([image]/[image]) and a number counting how many tasks are running, which when clicked, will show running tasks. You can also use the `Tasks: Show Running Tasks` command in the command palette.

If you have Accessibility mode turned on, then you can also use the `accessibility.alert.taskCompleted` setting.

Note that in VS Code 1.87, the schema for audio cues and accessibility alerts are merged into "signals" settings (see issue ticket [#202018](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/202018)).

There is also the extension [`joelrobichaud.vscode-task-notifier`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=joelrobichaud.vscode-task-notifier) <sup><sub>(I have no affiliation with this extension)</sub></sup> that will create a *system* notification when a task has finished.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a build watcher running and you want some UI feedback of when it starts and finishes you can use the extension [Notify On File](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.notify-on-file) that I wrote.

You can show/remove a status bar item or show an Information Notification when a file is created/deleted/changed.

You can use it by creating a sentinel file at the build start and remove it after the build finishes.

An example configuration:

```json
  "notify-on-file.notify": {
    "path": "${workspaceFolder}",
    "globPattern": ".vscode/build.txt",
    "onCreate": [
      { "showStatusBarItem": "build",
        "backgroundColor": "statusBarItem.warningBackground",
        "text": "$(watch) Building Application",
        "tooltip": "Time to get a drink"
      }
    ],
    "onDelete": [
      { "removeStatusBarItem": "build" }
      { "notify": "Build finished" }
    ]
  }
```

Giving the status bar item a background color makes it more visible when it is removed.

The sentinel file is `.vscode/build.txt` in the current workspace.

You can use files outside the workspace like: `/home/myname/tmp/build.txt`